# Can I disable notifications from a single site?

Tags: disqus

I'd like to receive Disqus notifications in general, except for a single site which generates tons of notifications for new comments.

Can I disable Disqus notifications from a single site?

Comment: This question is indescribably crucial. If you can't turn off notifications on a per-thread basis, the service is pretty much a flaw.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Disqus help docs it looks like you either get all of the notifications or none of them.

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466221-managing-notifications

Answer (score 0):

To disable email notifications from Disqus for a single site:

1. Click the top Notifications tab.
2. On the left, click Settings. Click Moderation.
3. Uncheck the box next to the site.
4. Scroll down and click Save.